# Cannot ssh using ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, putty

I'm trying to ssh using the ubuntu terminal into one of my machines. I'm connected to the machine's network using vpn. When I ssh using the flag `-v`, i get following output and then it gets stuck there indefinitely, This happens with another server as well. But when I use putty to access these servers/machines, it works fine. I reinstalled the `openssh-client openssh-server`, on my client, but still the same issue. Don't have direct access to the servers, so cannot remove the ssh server from them.

```
salman@salman-Latitude-5580:~$ ssh -v administrator@10.1.17.118
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.1.17.118 [10.1.17.118] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/salman/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/salman/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/salman/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/salman/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/salman/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/salman/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/salman/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/salman/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 10.1.17.118:22 as 'administrator'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
```

Answer (score 0):

Your host might not support the `host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256`.

Look at the debug output of putty for the supported algo, then specify the same for ssh:

```
ssh -o "HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-rsa" user@hostname
```